# Using Process.Start and shortPath on one computer it is working and on the other not

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm doing small software that reads from database names of applications to be open and open them automatically.

I developed it on one computer and create installation and install it on a few computers. All have Windows 7 and service pack 1. On all the computers it is working except one.

On this computer I get the following error:

> 'C:\Users\Pulse\MYDOCU~1\jdjdkjdjskjs.xlsx' could not be found. Check
>   the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is
>   correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently use
>   files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved or deleted.

The path is created correctly and the error is only in the file name. The characters that it creates are different for each execution (although the file name is the same).

The following is the code I use:

```
StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(255);
GetShortPathName(fileName, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
Process.Start(commandLine, shortPath.ToString());
```

Where the data for filename and commandLine I read from a Database.
What needs to be corrected here?

Comment: The code you gave is is not very helpful, you need to give us the code for `GetShortPathName`, also the statement "*The path is created correctly and the error is only in the file name. The characters that it creates is deferent for each running (although the file name is the same).*" does that mean the long name is the same every time but the short name is different? Also is the text really "jdjdkjdjskjs" or did you replace the filename, please give us real names as it affects the decisions of what it could be.

Comment: Why do you need to use the short path at all?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is WinAPI. The rest of your comment is spot on, though. :-)

Comment: Is it possible that short name generation has been [disabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007) on that machine?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I could see two reasons, 1. You don't need to handle escaping spaces in the path you pass as an argument to the next program, 2. (not applicable in this case) if you need to do some kind of path joining it decreases the chances of going over the max file path length in windows. Also OP, can you please include the P/Invoke statement for `GetShortPathName` so we can check that for errors. Lastly can you do a `dir /X` in the folder for that file and show us what it outputs for the long name and short name for that file?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `GetShortPathName` is returning the correct value? Edit your question and show us your managed prototype (i.e. `DllImport` and `static extern ...`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. here are the answer to your questions:
1. The name that the function created is not what I write, it create a name that mostly has special characters so I can't copy it.
2. GetShortPathName is a function of windows API, so I can't give the code for it. It is not my code. In addition it is work on other computers and only on one computer of a customer it is not working.

Comment: In continue to my last comment:
3. It is happened on this computer for any type of file I tried (word and excel). On all other computers it is working with all types of files.
Hope this will help somehow.
Thanks